# Syntax error in php response

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP proxy which calls a HTTPS web service.

The response of PHP proxy is sent back to the JavaScript . I see a proper response(XML) in my browser . However in the JavaScript I do not get any response . In the console I see a error reported as `SyntaxError:syntax error` for the PHP file.

The php file is

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://xomw764dei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getAllServerMachines';
  //$url = func_get_arg(0);
  $callback = $_GET["callback"];

  //echo($callback . "(");
  echo(file_get_contents($url . '/' . $_GET["poolingServer"]));
  //echo (")");
?>
```

php Response

```
<getAllServerMachinesResponse xmlns="http://xomw764dei.dsone.3ds.com/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc"><getAllServerMachinesResult>thunderw7dei</getAllServerMachinesResult></getAllServerMachinesResponse>
```

javascript code
This is a wrapper upon the javascript provided by netvibes. We are using a UWA framework

```
uri = 'http://localhost:1136/ServerTools.php?poolingServer=' + MyWidget.poolingServerName.toString();

////////////////////////

UWA.Data.proxies.rest = uri;
//UWA.Data.request('http://',{
UWA.Data.request(uri.toString(), {
    timeout: 50000,
    proxy: 'rest',
    cors: true,
    type: 'xml',
    method: 'POST',
    onComplete: function funcCompleteA(obj) {
        alert("On Complete A");
    },
    onFailure: funcFail
});
```

Comment: please add the javascript code (as that is the part where you get no response)

Comment: @GitaarLAB Added the js call

Comment: I don't know UWA. But I have a sneaky suspicion that `$callback` is needed in your php. It appears you are passing a string (the source from the external website), so you'd probably also need to quote that string you are passing into your javascript as `obj` arg for function `funcCompleteA`. Did you try that?

Comment: @GitaarLAB Well I did not get when u say "need to quote that string you are passing into your javascript "

Comment: php's `file_get_contents` returns a string. So, `callback` (when used) should result in `$callback('your string from file_get_contents')`. However, I also see your UWA code seems to expect xml. I'm still looking at the doc.

Comment: Could it be that `UWA.Data` uses proxy-servers from netvibe (and not your own php proxy)? See: http://fdp.frogcommunity.com/questions/view/17 and http://uwa.netvibes.com/docs/Uwa/html/static-FAQ.html talks about: `By setting the "exposition" property of UWA.hosts you ask UWA to use your UWA instance for cross-domain Ajax requests.

Notice that this script tag will be ignored once the app is compiled on another platform because it overides the UWA namespace.
 - The UWA.hosts overide should be in a separate script tag
 - The script tag should be inserted before the standalone emulation files
`

Comment: @GitaarLAB  I changed the ResponseFormat to json . Now I get a different error [14:06:47.042] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @ http://localhost:1136/ServerTools.php?poolingServer=thunderw7dei&callback=jsonp1409733407493&callbackMode=function:1